# How to tell hibernate validator to validate only one annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is it possible to tell hibernate validation to validate only one particular annotation ?
I've created custom annotation which use `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` so far so good.
However when I want to manually validate Object using

```
javax.validation.Validator.validate(myOjbect);
```

it will validate all annotations including @NotNull, @Size... Is there an elegant way to override this behaviour so I can choose which annotations to validate ?

Comment: I updated my answer because using the grouping approach as documented is possible safer: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I rewrite it using groups and it works as intented :)

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer again to only contain the approach using groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to limit validation to a particular annotation without modifying the validated class.  You can limit it to a property by calling `Validator##validateProperty(object, propertyName, ...)` but the equivalent to explicitly limit it to a set of annotations requires to [assign groups to annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups):

What seemes to work is this:

1. Create an interface for each group of annotations you want to validate.
2. Specify that interface for `groups` property of each annotation to validate with this group. If the annotation also must be validated by default, add the `Default` interface either.
3. Add the interface to validator invocations.

An example:

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public class SomeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Cat a = new Cat(null);
        // invalid: name is null
        output(validator.validate(a), a);

        Cat b = new Cat("?");
        // invalid: name too short
        output(validator.validate(b), b);

        // valid: only @NotNull is evaluated, @Size does not matter.
        output(validator.validate(b, NotNullName.class), b);

        // invalid: only @NotNull is evaluated, @Size does not matter. Name is null.
        output(validator.validate(a, NotNullName.class), a);
    }

    /**
     * Output validation result.
     *
     * @param validate
     *            the validate
     */
    private static void output(Set<ConstraintViolation<Cat>> validationResult, Cat cat) {
        if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(cat + " is valid!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(cat + " is invalid!\n" + validationResult);
        }
    }

    // no need to implement an interface - just name it for annotation groups attribute:
    public static class Cat {
        @NotNull(groups = { NotNullName.class, Default.class })
        @Size(min = 3, max = 45)
        private String name;

        public Cat(String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("Cat [");
            if (name != null) {
                builder.append("name=");
                builder.append(name);
            }
            builder.append("]");
            return builder.toString();
        }

    }

    public static interface NotNullName {
        // no members needed here
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cat [] is invalid!
[ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='darf nicht null sein', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class SomeTest$Cat, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}, ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='darf nicht null sein', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class SomeTest$Cat, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}]
Cat [name=?] is invalid!
[ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Länge muss zwischen 3 und 45 liegen', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class SomeTest$Cat, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}]
Cat [name=?] is valid!
Cat [] is invalid!
[ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='darf nicht null sein', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class SomeTest$Cat, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}]
```